# Change Paste Location without Hardwiring. Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

```
   Sub FindProj() 
    Dim Lastrow As Long
    Dim Newproj As Long
    Lastrow = Sheets("Historical").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    Newproj = Sheets("Data").Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    Sheets("Historical").Cells(Lastrow, "B").Copy Sheets("Data").Cells(Newproj - 30, "C")

    End Sub
```

Is there a way to change the last half of the last line of code to **Sheets("Data").Cells(Newproj - Master + 1, "C")**?

As in, I want the information to be pasted to the last row of the table before the table became longer due to the "Master" template being pasted.
So, if the last row was 100, the table has 32 rows. This means the new last row is 132.

Currently, my code only pastes in the correct row because I calculated that I have to paste the value 30 rows prior in 101 with math.
If ever I change my template dimensions, I would have to go into the code and change the "30" to "31" for example or "35", depending on the new number of rows.

I don't want it hardwired. I want it to change depending on the variables, just like the rest of my code.

Master Template is a range in the  "data" worksheet.
Main table is called "**Historical**", dimensions are 30 columns wide by however many rows happen to be in the table. 
**Master** template is a table within "**Historical**" that is 30 columns wide by 32 rows tall i.e. the first 32 rows of the "Historical" table.

I am trying to paste the Master table at the end of the table and then paste a value from another source in cell 1,1 of the newly pasted table.

I want to do this without hard-wiring the dimensions of the Master template because those dimensions might change over time.

Comment: You've provided no indication that I can determine exactly what or where *'the "Master" template'* is.

Comment: @Jeeped Master template is a section of a data table that is copied and pasted at the end of the table when a new project is added. In my current case, it it the first 32 rows of my table.

Comment: Well, then use *the *'Master" template'*.rows.count in your maths.

Comment: @Jeeped Is that an actual command? And to be clear, "Master" is a table. Are you saying to replace the Sheets("Data").Cells(Newproj - 30, "C") with Sheets("Data").Cells("Master"template'.rows.count?

Comment: @Jeeped or Sheets("Data").Cells(Newproj - "Master"Template', "C")?

Comment: what/where is _Master template_? Is it a range in what columns of what worksheet in what workbook? Give ALL the details about it

Comment: @DisplayName Master Template is a range in the "Data" worksheet.

Comment: you may want to add some screenshots of a "before" and "after" scenario

Comment: See above for explanation edit.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with below code

```
Sub FindProj()
     Dim Lastrow As Long
     Dim Newproj As Long
     Dim hist As Worksheet
     Dim data As Worksheet
     Set hist = Worksheets("Historical")
     Set data = Worksheets("Data")
     Lastrow = hist.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
     Newproj = data.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
     hist.Range("B1:B" & Lastrow).Copy data.Range("C" & data.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1)
 End Sub
```

Comment: I had to modify the last line to "B" from "B1:B" as it was picking up all cells in the column as opposed to just the last cell. In my "Data" worksheet, it pastes on the last row after Master template. So, on row 133 as opposed to row 101. Is there a way to subtract the template so the value from my Historical worksheet pastes in the correct location?